# Exclude group of records—if number ever goes up

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle18c

I have a road inspection table:

```
INSPECTION_ID         ROAD_ID       INSP_DATE CONDITION_RATING
--------------------- ------------- --------- ----------------
506411                3040          01-JAN-81               15
508738                3040          14-APR-85               15
512461                3040          22-MAY-88               14
515077                3040          17-MAY-91               14 -- all ok

505967                3180          01-MAY-81               11
507655                3180          13-APR-85                9
512374                3180          11-MAY-88               17 <-- goes up; NOT ok
515626                3180          25-APR-91             16.5

502798                3260          01-MAY-83               14
508747                3260          13-APR-85               13
511373                3260          11-MAY-88               12
514734                3260          25-APR-91               12  -- all ok
```

---

I want to write a query that will exclude the entire road -- if the road's condition ever goes up over time. For example, exclude road `3180`, since the condition goes from 9 to 17 (an anomaly).

**Question:**

How can I do that using Oracle SQL?

---

Sample data: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1d3585eed11e2a27017a4645b80d6eaa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

- find "next" `condition_rating` value (within the same `road_id` - that's the `partition by` clause, sorted by `insp_date`)
- return `road_id` whose difference between the "next" and "current" `condition_rating` is less than zero

---

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select road_id,
  3            condition_rating,
  4            nvl(lead(condition_rating) over (partition by road_id order by insp_date),
  5                condition_rating) next_cr
  6     from test
  7    )
  8  select distinct road_id
  9  from temp
 10  where condition_rating - next_cr < 0;

   ROAD_ID
----------
      3180

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if the `nvl()` is needed? Or is it just a preference thing? It looks like the result is the same with or without the `nvl()`.

Comment: The last row doesn't have "next" values so LEAD returns NULL. In that case, you'd be subtracting "something - NULL" which is always NULL, and that's not *less than zero* so you might get unexpected result. NVL function sets it (the NULL) to the same value of the last row's CONDITION_RATING; it means that you'll actually subtract CONDITION_RATING - CONDITION_RATING which is equal to 0 (but is not *less than zero*) so that row won't be returned.

Comment: I appreciate your help! By the way, did you like or dislike the way I provided the sample data? I want to include sample data in my questions in the way that's **most convenient for SO answerers.**

Comment: Like, as it was easy to create test case visiting db<>fiddle. If you posted just a "table" (the one in question), anyone - who'd want to use sample data - would have to type everything manually.

Answer (score 1):

Based on OPs own answer, which make the expected outcome more clear.

In my permanent urge to avoid self-joins I'd go for the nested window function:

```
SELECT road_id, condition_rating, insp_date
  FROM ( SELECT prev.*
              , COUNT(CASE WHEN condition_rating < next_cr THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY road_id) bad
           FROM (select t.*
                      , lead(condition_rating) over (partition by road_id order by insp_date) next_cr
                  from t
                ) prev
       ) tagged
WHERE bad = 0
ORDER BY road_id, insp_date
```

**NOTE**

- `lead()` gives `null` for the last row which the query considers by the `case` expression to mark bad rows: `condition_rating < next_cr` — if `next_cr` is `null`, the condition won't be true so that the `case` maps it as "not bad".
- The `case` is just to mimic the `filter` clause: https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter
- `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` might be another option to this problem, but due to the lack of '^' and '$' I'm worried that the backtracking might cause more problems it is worth.
- Nested window functions are typically no big performance hit if they use compatible `OVER` clauses, like in this query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that's similar to @Littlefoot's answer:

```
with insp as (
select 
    road_id,
    condition_rating,
    insp_date,
    case when   condition_rating   >   lag(condition_rating,1) over(partition by road_id order by insp_date)   then 'Y'   end as condition_goes_up
from 
    test_data
)

select
    insp.*
from
    insp
left join
    (
    select distinct
        road_id,
        condition_goes_up
    from
        insp
    where
        condition_goes_up = 'Y'
    ) insp_flag
    on insp.road_id = insp_flag.road_id
where
    insp_flag.condition_goes_up is null

--Note: I removed the ORDER BY, because I think the window function already orders the rows the way I want.
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3fee5d9b1ab02eb4ae526515e21967b7)

---

**Edit:**

Here's a version that's similar to what @Markus Winand did:

```
insp as (
select 
    road_id,
    condition_rating,
    insp_date,
    case when   condition_rating   >   lag(condition_rating,1) over(partition by road_id order by insp_date)   then 'Y'   end as condition_goes_up
from 
    test_data
)

select
    insp_tagged.*
from
    (
    select
        insp.*,
        count(condition_goes_up) over(partition by road_id) as condition_goes_up_count
    from
        insp
    ) insp_tagged
where
    condition_goes_up_count = 0
```

I ended up going with that option.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c98e12271f1b40c20efa4010f6861dd2)